# Why does it not find the variable?

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, nameerror

So below is my code, and I need to get the variable 'p' from the Entry widget, set it as a new variable name, the print it. For some reason, I get the following error 'NameError: name 'p' is not defined'. I have absolutely no idea how to fix it and this is my last resort. Please help me.

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk   # python3
#import Tkinter as tk   # python

self = tk
TITLE_FONT = ("Helvetica", 18, "bold")

#-------------------FUNCTIONS-------------------#
def EnterP():
    b1 = p.get()
    print (p.get())

def EnterS(*self):
    print (self.s.get())

def EnterB(*args):
    print (b.get())

def EnterN(*args):
    print (n.get())
#-----------------------------------------------#

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # the container is where we'll stack a bunch of frames
        # on top of each other, then the one we want visible
        # will be raised above the others
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (Home, Population, Quit):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            # put all of the pages in the same location;
            # the one on the top of the stacking order
            # will be the one that is visible.
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("Home")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


class Home(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Home Page", font=TITLE_FONT)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Population",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame("Population"))
        button5 = tk.Button(self, text = "Quit",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame("Quit"))
        button1.pack()
        button5.pack()


class Population(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Enter Generation 0 Values",     font=TITLE_FONT)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        #Population Number
        w = tk.Label(self, text="Enter the value for the Population")
        w.pack()

        p = tk.Entry(self)
        p.pack()

        pb = tk.Button(self, text="OK", command = EnterP)
        pb.pack()

        #Survival Rates
        w = tk.Label(self, text="Enter the value of Survival Rates")
        w.pack()

        s = tk.Entry(self)
        s.pack()

        sb = tk.Button(self, text="OK", command = EnterS)
        sb.pack()

        #Birth Rates
        w = tk.Label(self, text="ENter the value for the Birth Rate")
        w.pack()

        b = tk.Entry(self)
        b.pack()

        bb = tk.Button(self, text="OK", command = EnterB)
        bb.pack()

        #Number of New Generations To Model
        w = tk.Label(self, text="Enter the number of New Generatiions")
        w.pack()

        n = tk.Entry(self)
        n.pack()

        nb = tk.Button(self, text="OK", command = EnterN)
        nb.pack()


        button = tk.Button(self, text="<<< BACK",
                       command=lambda: controller.show_frame("Home"))
        button.pack()



class Quit(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Are you sure you want to quit?", font=TITLE_FONT)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)


        yes = tk.Button(self, text="Yes")
        yes.pack()

        no = tk.Button(self, text = "No",
                   command = lambda: controller.show_frame("Home"))
        no.pack()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

modify your code like this:

```
class Population(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        def EnterP():
            b1 = p.get()
            print (p.get())
```

Comment: OMG. Thank you soooo much. Your a lifesaver. So do the functions have to be with the class that needs them??

Comment: no need, you can defined it as a method of the class. You need learn more to figure-out it. Actually, your code is not so good and the question is not a good question ,that's why someone give you negative vote.

Comment: I don't see any advantage to nesting a function inside the init. The better fix is to understand scoping, and to make `p` an instance variable rather than a local variable.

Comment: As I point out, he should defind it as a menthod of the class. But base on the codes, seems he don't know too much of python and even has not concpet of scope. I just give him a quick answer. When he learn enough, he will found imprving the code is a easy thing.

Comment: Yes. As Howard said, I don;t know that much about python. I'm trying to do complicated things and sometimes and need help. ANy help I get is written down so I don;t make the same mistake. I'm still learning!!!

Answer (score 0):

I won't try to give a complete answer (for there might be more that one error in your program), but let me tell you what your problem is:

You didn't take into account **variable scopes**. Whenever naming a variable, it is only accessible in a specific region of your code.

In your code, for instance, `p` is defined inside `class Population.__init__` scope. `EnterP` is defined **outside** of this scope, hence cannot access `p`.

Each language has its own way to handle such scopes. Here is something you should read on this topic:

https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Variables_and_Scope.html

Good luck!

Comment: Ahh ok. Thanks for this. I didn't know about that but looking at the web link, it is becoming more clearer.